# Automatic demo generation from tests in react

Tags: reactjs, automation, documentation

I am developing a React app and try to maintain a demo page with examples for users. Every time I redesign something, however, I need to update the demo also. It is not much of a problem, however, its getting really tedious and I was wandering whether it can be done automatically, for example, as a result of unit tests.

My question is: Can the process of recording examples be automated with some existing javascript library? Did you came across a project that did something similar?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Of course. I have a page with a demo on the GitHub wiki. There is a bunch of use cases showing usage of the app. Each use case is shown as a gif/screenshot that I captured. What I want is to be able to automate the process of generating these gifs/screenshots whenever I add functionality or redesign components. I was wondering whether I would be able to connect such a generation to the code itself so that the demo page would be easier to maintain.

Comment: So you want to automate the generation of gifs/screenshots. I am not quite sure I understand your goal quite well, have you considered using webdriver.io to do that, there is an extension which records your tests: https://webdriver.io/ https://webdriver.io/docs/wdio-video-reporter/ what's the link to ur github wiki?

Comment: I can't link the GitHub wiki page as it is on a private GitHub instance. But really thanks for the webdriver.io link! That does look like something I was looking for.

Comment: Great to hear it might help, good luck